# days are determined

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

transcription:

```
days are determined...

your final answer should describe what this puzzle should be

1
end of the day

4
us state

6
1971 french open quarter-
finalist for women's singles

2
tie the knot

7
loud noise

5
search for items

3
quenched
```

Comment: The transcription at the bottom seems like it's missing some information compared to the picture, namely the coloring and which boxes have circles - is there a way of representing that in the transcription as well as the numbers and clues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This puzzle should be

> TWEAKED!

The clued words are:

> [image]
>  The yellow letters are the days of the week.

Taking the circled letters

> and ordering them by the numbers next to the clues gives the word TWEAKED.

Comment: Oof, snap! Seconds in it :) +1 for the successful solve

Comment: Haha, nice job. +1 for you too.

Answer (score 10):

First let's solve the clues, noticing the pattern in each answer as we go:

> Namely, that the three shaded squares contain an **abbreviated day of the week** (Sun, Mon, Tue, etc.), in turn:
>
>  1 end of the day = [sun]se**T**
>  4 us state = [mon]t**A**na
>  6 1971 french open quarter-finalist for women's singles = [[tu**E**]ro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linda_Tuero)
>  2 tie the knot = [**W**ed]
>  7 loud noise = [thu]**D**
>  5 search for items = [fri]s**K**
>  3 quenched = [sat]**E**d
>
>  In other words, as suggested by the title, these cells' values are pre-*determined* to be *days* of the week.

Now look at the numbers beside each clue...

> Since these are numbered 1 to 7, these suggest we should extract the circled letters from each word and reorder them according to this numbering. Doing so produces the word **TWEAKED**.
>
>  All of which fits thematically, since we conclude that 'this puzzle must be **tweaked**' - in that we had to reorder ('tweak' the arrangement of) the letters to form this final password, and this word contains a homophone of 'week' within its pronunciation.
>
>  (At least that's what I *thought* the relevance of 'tweaked' was, until [this wonderful follow-on puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116043/since-his) was posted immediately after this one was solved...!)