# "S᠎i᠎n᠎c᠎e᠎ his

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

It looks like I've found part of a puzzle? I wonder where the rest of it is! It should be around here somewhere...

Once you do find it, you might find this transcription of some of the text in the puzzle helpful:

```
"Since his

now that it has been TWEAKED,
when spoken aloud.

Numbers 1:3 
One who might work after the

Numbers 13: 
In a delirio

Genesis 40: 
Dutch
and semi-

Numbers 7:7 
In order to finish putting on this garment, you have to

Joshua 19:1 
It could be the source of a lot of

Numbers 1:1
Place where a salvager might

Genesis 46:2
Minty offering that might cause a thirst to be

Genesis 49:19   
Increase    

Luke 2:25   
Divide  

1 Chronicles 12:26  
Squid's cousin  

Genesis 35:18   
Original    

Joshua 15:20    
Render harmless, as a cat   

Exodus 1:1-5                                                                        
(3 5 4) → "(3 6)"
```

Comment: Oh, this is beautiful! What a clever collaboration - well done both of you :) It's midnight here so I'll have to leave this to the 'night crew' but I shall look forward to having a go myself when I wake up. Lovely job!

Comment: This is, in my opinion, the most brilliant puzzle ever crafted on this site. My hat's off to you, @noneuclideanisms.

Comment: @Stiv collaboration, or two accounts from the same person? (Which [is allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/295232), with some limitations.) Note that the usernames are anagrams of each other.

Comment: @Glorfindel That is an excellent spot - not something I'd ever noticed before! Either way, wonderfully coordinated and so satisfying to experience :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Now that this puzzle has been tweaked,

> IT'S HOLIER

First you have to recognize that

> the blank area in this puzzle's image is [this other puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116039/days-are-determined) Then you combine them to make this image:
>  [image]

The clues are solved like so

> [image]
>  Notice that the yellow cells now spell the months of the year.

Each clue has a Bible verse.

> Each verse talks about one of the sons of Israel that went to Egypt with Jacob. These are shown in the image above.

Finally, Exodus 1:1-5

> lists them in order. Taking the circled letters in the order indicated by the names yields the string ITSWHOLEYEAR.
> [image]
> This makes sense because we have all the months of the year.
> `(3 5 4) → "(3 6)"` shows the enumeration for the literal solution and its homophone when spoken aloud.

When spoken aloud

> It's holier!